# Keycloak: Login Disabled User Gives HTTP 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: keycloak

I'm using version 3.4.3 of Keycloak. When I deactivate a user using `PUT` and setting the `enabled` flag to false, he cannot login anymore. This is exactly what I want. However, instead of a HTTP status code 403 (Access denied) or 401 (Unauthorized) that I'd expect to get from a login attempt of a deactivated user, I get a 400 (Bad Request) instead. When I reactivate the user, using `PUT` and setting the `enabled` flag back to `true`, he can login again.

Here's my `curl` script:

```
token=`cat .file_containing_admins_token`
curl -v -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" --data "{\"enabled\": false}" "http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/[my-realm]/users/[user-id-to-block]"
```

The [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/3.4/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource) is rather terse on status codes.

There's also a second, more specific API endpoint `PUT /{realm}/users/{id}/disable-credential-types`. But there I am missing to re-enable the credential, which is a requirement for my use case.

Comment: On keycloak 4.3.0, I get 200 Ok response code with the message "Account is disabled, contact admin." (when disabled user logs in through browser)

Comment: @tryingToLearn 200 for a unsuccessful login attempt? Really?

Comment: yes. Will try to share screenshot when i get back to my pc.